# ServiceWorkers and cookies

Tags: javascript, html, cookies, fetch, service-worker

Our serviceworker does one thing: It forwards every request to the server and when the server is offline the serviceworker catches the exception and displays an "offline" page.

The documentation says that in order for serviceworkers to send cookies one needs to define the credentials, like this:

```
fetch(url, {
    credentials: "same-origin"
}).then(...).catch(...);
```

QUESTION: We do not set credentials, so why is our server still receiving the cookies when we use this code:

```
self.addEventListener('fetch', function(event) {
    event.respondWith(
        fetch( event.request ).catch(function(error) {
                return caches.open('offline').then(function(cache) {
                    return cache.match("/offline.html");
            });
        })
    );
});
```

PS: We are happy about that but not sure why it is working

Answer (score 0):

Cookies are always sent for same-origin requests that are not initiated by `fetch()`. For example, consider the page below:

#### index.html

Cookies are sent with the "index.html" request itself and for these resources declared within it:

```
<link rel="style.css">
<img src="image.jpg">
<script src="script.js"></script>
```

Same-origin requests in your scripts would not send cookies by default:

```
<script>
  // cookies not sent
  fetch('style.css')

  // cookies sent
  fetch('style.css', {credentials: "same-origin"})
</script>
```

Comment: But the service worker takes control of EVERY request when we initiate it with "self.addEventListener"
and then it is calling the page with the fetch(request). So how come the cookies are sent?

Comment: I did further testing: The request object actually contains already the credential settings. So fetch( event.request.url ) would not work, while fetch( event.request ) will work

Comment: Yes, the answer above accounts for the service worker controlling the page. Only certain requests send cookies unless your service worker alters the Request